# Как получить объект из связанной таблицы?

Tags: python, django

Есть таблица с комментариями Comments, в которой есть поле ForeignKey (User) и есть таблица User2, содержащая расширенные сведения о пользователе и в которой есть поле ForeignKey (User).

Как для объекта из таблицы Comments получить дополнительные сведения о пользователе из таблицы User2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
users2 = comment.user.user2_set.all()
if users2.exists():
    user2 = users2[0]
```

Так как у вас User2 ссылается на User с помощью ForeignKey, то теоретически может оказаться, что юзер может иметь несколько User2 либо не иметь вовсе. Поэтому мы достаем их все, проверяем, есть ли они вообще, и берем первый попавшийся.

Comment: Только лучше вообще для профиля использовать `OneToOneField`, а не `ForeignKey`